# why is system.out.println using 2-d arrays giveing error?

Tags: java

I am trying to populate my 2-D array with random intergers. The only issue I am having is the last system.out.println(); is highlighted in red. It says error can't resolve symbol 'println'

```
            int[][] array = new int[row][col];
            for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j <= col; j++) {
                System.out.println(j);
            }
            array[row][col] = ((int)(Math.random() * 10));
            System.out.println(array[row][col]);

        }
     // this last line is highlighted in red 
        System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hint: start with indenting your code *properly* (let your editor do it for you if you can to avoid human errors). Then see where that last printing statement is placed. But to be fair this error message is indeed confusing.

Comment: probably your braces are not balanced

Comment: @Pshemo nevermind braces are balanced and error is still there, also random int stopped populating

Comment: @TheScientificMethod braces are balanced , still has error

Comment: Can you share a bit more code, near the top of the method? Is you last `System.out.println()` inside a method?

Comment: Adding indentation doesn't affect how code works in Java, so it isn't that your code doesn't work *anymore* but it wasn't correct even before indenting it. But fixing indentation wouldn't fix errors, it would only let us spot them easier, so if you solved the current error and have new one you must have changed something aside from indentation. Update your question and include your current code, along with expected result and description of result you wanted to achieve.

Comment: You should get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` from your code, as you are accessing beyond the last element in your `array` -- you have `row` elements on the first level, so accessing the `row`th element (zero-indexed) will be one past the last element.

Comment: @vlumi everything is inside the main method , by zero-indexed do you mean I should change it to 1?

Comment: @Pshemo the array takes user input and generates the row & col then populate with random int

Comment: make the <= into <

Comment: @JeremyKahan errors still there nothing changed

Comment: because you are using row and col where you want i and j. Also, you need to do the assignments within the for loops and nest the for loops in each other.

Comment: @JeremyKahan I added some space to get it to print like a chart not sure if that was the error

Comment: @JeremyKahan it doesn't print like the output above after I change the <

Comment: Right, it will print 0 1 2 3 for column headers and 0 .. 5 for row numbers. If you don't care for those, you can add 1 before printing, but not to the index values. I'm working on formatting more like what you are suggesting.

Comment: I guess @ALOK VERMA has given answer which is relevant to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public  class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row;
    int col;

    System.out.println("row?");
        row = sc.nextInt ();


    System.out.println("column?");
        col = sc.nextInt ();

    int[][] array = new int[row][col];

            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {


            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

            array[i][j] = ((int)(Math.random() * 10));

            }

            }

            for(int i = 0 ;i < row ;i++) {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < col ; j++) {
                    System.out.print(array[i][j] );

                }
                     System.out.println();
                }


   }
}
```

Comment: it was just for printing the 2-d array

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care not to go beyond the end of the arrays, so the <= need to be <. You also want to use the for loops within each other to get the indices right. Thus:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Array {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row;
    int col;

    System.out.println("row?");
    row = sc.nextInt();


    System.out.println("column?");
    col = sc.nextInt();


    int[][] array = new int[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {


            array[i][j] = ((int)(Math.random() * 10));

            System.out.println("row " + i + " column " + j + " " + array[i][j]);
        }
    }


    // this last line is highlighted in red 
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

REVISION: now with pretty print of table:

````
       import java.util.*;
   public class Array {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           int row;
           int col;

           System.out.println("row?");
           row = sc.nextInt();


           System.out.println("column?");
           col = sc.nextInt();
           System.out.print("```|");
           for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
               System.out.print("   " + j);
           }
           System.out.println();
           for (int j = 0; j <= col; j++) {
               System.out.print("----");
           }
           System.out.println();
           //if you want to print any header inforation or the values of row and column, do it here outside of the loops
           int[][] array = new int[row][col];
           for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
               System.out.print(i + "  |");


               for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {


                   array[i][j] = ((int)(Math.random() * 10));

                   System.out.print("   " + array[i][j]); //feel free to add vertical bars here if you wish
               }
               System.out.println();

           }
       }
   }
````

Comment: I just ran this at https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/ and input 5 and 3 without error. What did you put in?

Comment: but probably I should have explained better. My guess is somewhere else not in the above, you are still going out of bounds. The rows are indexed 0, 1, 2, ... row -1. The columns are 0, 1, 2, ..., column-1. So if you are comparing indices like i and j to row and column like above, you want to make sure they are strictly less than row and column respectively before using them. Otherwise you get the out of bounds error. That's what @vlumi was saying.

Comment: you changed < back to <=. That is what is causing the out of bounds. You will want to change my println to a print with the number and a space. You will want to put a println outside the for j loop but inside the for i loop.

Comment: added pretty print of table with row and column numbers. If you really want those to start at 1 not 0, print (i+1) and (j+1) where I do i and j